# Reload the same SPA page when navigate

Tags: kendo-ui, single-page-application

I have a SPA using [kendo router](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/spa/router).

The spa is working fine when I navigate between different routes. But when I navigate to the same route that I am already on, nothing happens so the data presented is not updated.

For instance:

I am at: `http:localhost/MyApp#/MyPage`

If I do:

```
//Change some data...
myRouter.navigate("/Mypage");
```

nothing happens.

The callback defined by:

```
myRouter.route("/MyPage", function(){
   //this is not executed when I navigate to the same page
});
```

is not fired.

How can I force to navigate in that condition (to the same page)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you want to navigate to the same page? Why not execute the handler directly if that's what you want?

Comment: @OnaBai Ok. I changed my code to follow your recomendation. But can you explain me why it doesn't force the navigation to the same route? It is supposed to be like this?